# Setting initial value ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I want to set and initial value, using `ng-options` , my values change the height and the width of the element and they repeat using `ng-repeat`, I'm wondering how to solve this, hope you guys can help me

html:

```
<select
       ng-options="init as initSize for s.width + ' X ' + s.height  s in sizes"
       ng-model="bannerSizes">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.sizes = [
    { width: 320, height: 600, chatContainer: 430 },
    { width: 320, height: 320, chatContainer: 147 },
    { width: 336, height: 320, chatContainer: 147 },
    { width: 320, height: 320, chatContainer: 147 },
];
$scope.initSize = $scope.sizes[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add `<option value=""></option>` as you did.

The `ng-model` was set to `bannerSizes`, it should be `initSize`

check the demo link;

### http://jsfiddle.net/srm16hhb/1/

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-options="s as (s.width + ' X ' + s.height) for s in sizes" ng-model="initSize"></select>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.sizes = [{
        width: 320,
        height: 600,
        chatContainer: 430
    }, {
        width: 320,
        height: 320,
        chatContainer: 147
    }, {
        width: 336,
        height: 320,
        chatContainer: 147
    }, {
        width: 320,
        height: 320,
        chatContainer: 147
    }, ];
    $scope.initSize = $scope.sizes[0];
}
```

Comment: Hi Jossef, first of all thank you so much for this answer, it solved the problem and set and initial value but when I try to choose another one it doesn't work, tried this: 
<div class="banner" ng-style="{'width' : s.width + 'px', 'height' : s.height + 'px'}"> but no results.

Comment: Hehe had a problem with the bidding due to the scope, but I solved that problem thank you so much.